# Как посмотреть какие таблицы были удалены в базе данных MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Можно ли посмотреть какие таблицы были удалены из базы даннах за всё время её существования? И если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: если не вёлся аудит за "всё время", то никак

Comment: @Konst А вот у каждой базы данных есть .log файл, туда что сохраняется? Там нет информации об удаленных таблицах?

Comment: это как правило системный лог, туда не пишутся события по работе с объектами конкретной базы данных

Comment: если у вас сохранились архивы всех журналов транзакций, то можно что-то найти, например с помощью : https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/ru/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-sql-server/